# SQLServer Integration Services - Importando dados de arquivo. Usando nome do arquivo

Tags: sql-server, integração, ssis

Estou fazendo uma importação de arquivos dinamicos numa pasta. O nome é padronizado com DACOES*.csv. O SSIS está entendendo perfeitamente e funciona bem. Mas onde está o * tem o ano do arquivo (Ex.: 2020,2021,2022...). Como capturar a parte da string que compreende o ano do arquivo, no caso a partir do sétimo caractere até o "." que separa o nome da extensão?  Preciso desse dado para colocá-lo como conteúdo de uma coluna na tabela de destino.

Obrigado a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

vc pode usar a função COLUNA DERIVADA para gravar o nome do arquivo numa coluna da tabela. Abra seu fluxo de dados - Arraste a função COLUNA DERIVADA e deixe-a entre a ORIGEM e DESTINO, edit a coluna derivada e arraste a variável que vc criou com o diretório dos arquivos e solte na opção EXPRESSAO.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).